# wordpress admin is broken

Tags: wp-admin

I have just installed a fresh version of the latest wordpress locally but the backend admin area looks like this http://grab.by/iGik Not sure what is causing this, I have tried redownloading and reinstalling witha  new database but still doesnt work. uggh!

DEBUG INFO

I get the following error when I go to the updates page, but I have no errors or warnings on the homepage.

```
Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in /Volumes/data/Documents/websites/mrskitson2012/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2690
```

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: @toscho how do I add debug info? where do I find it?

Comment: Follow the link!

Comment: This is not solvable without debugging information.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I added what little debug info there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your browsers cache and reloading the page. That'll fix it.

There is an explaination [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/common-wordpress-errors-with-solutions/) (see problem number 2)

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: this did not work

Comment: @varun1505 maybe it did work, not even sure now, but it is working fine now.